# token is missing from jupyter lab

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, data-science, jupyter, jupyter-lab

[image]
[image]

I have attached two images above and neither of them shows a token. When I try to access this jupyter lab from my local host, it asks for a password/token.

Can you guys help me?

Thanks in advance

I have tried jupyter lab list as image attached above it is also not showing a token.

Comment: It looks like you may have set a password. Did you try setting a new one with `jupyter server password`?

Comment: Thanks, it was password issue, I reset the password